# how to know if mysql binary log is enable through sql command?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql instance running and I want to know if binary log is enable for that instance without logging into the machine and check my.cnf file. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'log_bin';
```

Answer (score 16):

After login Execute the following command

```
SHOW BINARY LOGS
```

If there is no binary logs then you will get a message similar to 'You are not using binary logging'

Comment: unlike the accepted answer this answer requires privileges; otherwise you will get an error like `ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 1: Access denied; you need the SUPER,REPLICATION CLIENT privilege for this operation`.  Furthermore, even if you have privs, the result may be an error, which will cause you extra work if you are doing this in a script or program.  `ERROR 1381 (HY000) at line 1: You are not using binary logging`

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT * from information_schema.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_NAME = 'LOG_BIN';
```

or

```
SELECT @@log_bin;
```

Comment: The second statement in this answer is the most useful of anything posted here because it returns a truthy/falsey value (ie 1,0) instead of a string ('ON','OFF').

Comment: `ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'GLOBAL_VARIABLES' in information_schema`